# Which cement or mortar will give best result when creating low water diversion barriers?

Tags: water, mortar, cement

I want to build up a short dam of maybe half an inch in height, to control where water is flowing.  The water flows as a small, steady trickle.  Right now it fans across a large-ish area.  I'd like to concentrate its flow to a specific area.

What kind of cement or mortar should I use to direct the flow?  I was thinking of hydraulic cement, but I wanted to check first.  The area is wet.  **I want to make sure the new cement sticks** to the existing thin cement floor in the cellar.

I also have some quick set mortar powder on hand, as well as some resurfacing cement.  If none of the products I have on hand is the right thing, I can buy something new.

I don't care about the aesthetics in this case.

Comment: why not just slope the floor gently?

Comment: @SolarMike - There's already a slope. // I don't want to tear up the floor and reconfigure the whole contour, and I don't want to resurface the whole thing.  (I'm not sure if that's what you were suggesting.)

Comment: I usually find new cement sticks well where it is not wanted, but otherwise does not stick... IMHO adding a 1/2" ridge is just a trip hazard, but your choice, which is why I suggested a slope as that detail was lacking in your question.

Comment: @SolarMike - Sorry I didn't mention the slope.  At any rate, the location would not create a tripping hazard.  It's under some stairs.  What do you think about the hydraulic cement?  I watched videos about it, and read the instructions.  The standard way to use it is to plug up a *hole*.  My situation is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydraulic cement sticks to wet fine, but you may need to abrade the surface to get to clean concrete, as it won't like a greasy, dirty or otherwise befouled surface.

**However, what I would actually do** (and have actually done) to direct water on a concrete floor is to use a diamond saw to cut a small channel into the surface - much neater and tidier - also easier to walk or roll over. And much less wet area.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try putting some leftover siding cleaner on it and scrubbing, and then rinse well.  Unfortunately I don't have a diamond saw.

Comment: You might be surprised how affordable a one-day rental is, if you don't get the absurdly large one. Depends on your local tool rental outlet, but they are not hard to come by.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.  If my first primitive attempt doesn't turn out, I'll try the diamond saw rental idea.